# Why would systemd start a service before a defined "After="?

Tags: systemd

So I have a raspberry PI OS lite running bookworm, and I have installed PulseAudio onto it.  The pi is setup to be a moonlight device for my TV (thanks Samsung for EoL SteamLink!).  All it has to do is boot up and auto launch moonlight, which is currently does.  This bit works fine.

*The issue...*

Because the pi is running the lite OS, as moonlight doesn't after need an X11 interface up and running as it runs its own, it means that pulse audio has had to be installed manually, as moonlight looks for that by default these days.

Pulse Audio, by default, is setup to only launch when a user logs in.  Thus because Moonlight doesn't need the pi to be logged in, and is being auto launched as a systemd service, it means that audio isn't ready for it, and no sound happens when launching a stream.

So, I have also created a pulseaudio systemd service to start up as a system service regardless of users, as per the instructions mentioned here (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/)

My pulse audio service file...

```
[Unit]
Description=PulseAudio system server
After=bluetooth.service

[Service]
Type=simple
PrivateTmp=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --system --realtime --log-target=journal --disallow-module-loading --disallow-exit
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I enable this service, and the reload and restart the system, if I then get a systemd plot of the services starting, it shows that the service is being started before the bluetooth service that I have defined.

[Systemd Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RfJt.jpg)

I have tried changing out to bluetooth.target, but this doesn't have any impact either.

I don't understand...

Comment: Note that systemd service units and definitions under `/etc/systemd/system/`override package/distribution defaults under `/lib/systemd/system/`  so be careful how and where  you edit unit files https://serverfault.com/q/840996/

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In systemd, what's the difference between After= and Requires=?](https://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires)

Comment: @EsaJokinen, yup tried using the "Requires=" and still doesn't make any difference.  I swapped out the after to requires, and changed to bluetooth.target, and systemd is still launching it before bluetooth.target is hit.  Unless I am reading the plot wrong?